# Why isn't my autolayout UI working?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to make a simple UI that should look like this:

[image]

Two views with equal widths with two views above them containing three icons aligned to the right with equal spacing between them.

So I have an invisible view above the red view with the same width, and inside that are the icons.

The icons all have nearest neighbor constraints as well as one connected to container margin like so:

[image]

But when I run it, it looks like this:

**iPhone 6:**
[image]

**iPhone 6 Plus:**
[image]

**iPhone 5S :**
[image]

*This is the invisible view:*

[image]

How can I make it work properly?

Comment: remove left alignment constraint and set the width of that buttons.

Answer (score 0):

While the different devices have different widths depending the position (landscape, portrait), the constraints connected to the container margin should have different values to satisfy all widths, but it seems you are setting it with static values.
I suggest to set a constraint between the separation of the most right image and the right side of the container, set a width constraint for each image and a separator constraint for the nearest neighbor image.